# Как заменить скобки на <span> внутри ссылки

Tags: html, jquery, замена, htmlspecialchars

Подскажите каким образом используя **jQuery** возможно внутри ссылки с классом `link` заменить символы `( )` на `<span></span>`, при условии что кроме скобок есть ещё и другой текст который `должен остаться не измененным` ?

Пример:

Сейчас:

```
<a class='link'>cars (10) </a>
```

Нужно:

```
<a class='link'>cars <span>10</span> </a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$("a.link").each(function() {
  $(this).html($(this).text().replace("(", "<span>").replace(")", "</span>"));
});
```

```css
a.link span {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class='link'>cars (10) </a>
<br/>
<a class='link'>trucks (28) </a>
```

Comment: Очень благодарен за помощь, а Вы могли бы сделать чтобы она все ссылки с классом link обрабатывала просто без привязки к нажатию?